# window.sqlitePlugin is undefined - but sqlite is installed

Tags: sqlite, cordova, cordova-plugins

I've tried to install this plugin https://github.com/xpbrew/cordova-sqlite-storage by `cordova-sqlite-storage`. I use framework7.

It's looks that the plugin is installed because when i type install command again i see

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\pj>cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage
Plugin "cordova-sqlite-storage" already installed on android.
Plugin "cordova-sqlite-storage" already installed on browser.
Adding cordova-sqlite-storage to package.json
```

This is the code where i use the sqlite:
routes.js

```
routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    url: './index.html',
  },
  {
    path: '/drive/',
    url: './pages/drive.html',
    on: {
      pageInit: function (e, page) {
        //db start

          window.sqlitePlugin.echoTest(function() {
            console.log('ECHO test OK');
            alert('ECHO test OK');
          });



          window.sqlitePlugin.selfTest(function() {
            console.log('SELF test OK');
            alert('SELF test OK');
          });

[...]
```

In console i see
`TypeError: window.sqlitePlugin is undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your index.html,
but before any scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/cordova-sqlite-storage/www/SQLitePlugin.js"></script>
<!-- your other scripts here -->
```